# Creating a Widget only application in Android?

Tags: android, android-widget

To clarify the question:

I have seen multiple Apps in the Playstore that are widget only Apps without visible activities.
I tried to create one myself but I need to define a launcher Activity. Once I use the configuration Activity of the Widget as a launcher the app becomes visible in the app overview in Android.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLUUd.png

If I dont define a launcher Activity I cant even deploy the app on the emulator.

The developerguide on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html about Widgets isnt really clear about how to handle this case.

Any help or directions where to find information is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to create a widget only android application without any activity. You don't have to declare any intents for your activity. Just pass the intent filter for `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE` It will make the activity load when the user adds it to their home screen. Now you can simply declare your configuration class with your widget layout xml file with `android:configure` attribute liking to the class file the widget runs on.

Hope this helps.